# Cant copy file to users in linux in this script

Tags: awk, copy

I am trying to make a bash script to copy files to all users directories.
But it works if there is only 1 user in system. If there are 2 Users it doenst work with the following error. Thanks in advance for all of your helps

Listed users:
Mahmut
smbguest

```
_USERS="$(eval getent passwd {$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)..$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)} | cut -d: -f1)"

UHOME="/home"

SAB="Şablonlar"
CONF=".config"
_FILESS="./Şablonlar/*"  

for u in $_USERS
do

  _dir="${UHOME}/${u}"


   for f in $_FILESS
   do

       mkdir "$_dir/${SAB}"
       cp -r "${f}" "$_dir/${SAB}"

       find "$_dir/${SAB}/" -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \+

       chown $(id -un $u):$(id -gn $u) "$_dir/${SAB}/"

done
done
```

**Output**

> ```
> mkdir: `/home/mahmut\nsmbguest/Şablonlar' cannot created: No such file or directory
> cp: normal file '/home/mahmut'$'\n''smbguest/Şablonlar' cannot created: No such file or directory
> find: ‘/home/mahmut\nsmbguest/Şablonlar/’: No such file or directory
> id: `mahmut\nsmbguest': no such user
> id: `mahmut\nsmbguest': no such user
> chown: '/home/mahmut'$'\n''smbguest/Şablonlar/' cannot accessed: No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], this is too broad to ask on [so].

Comment: thnks I summarized it

Answer (score 0):

This will show all "normal" users (that is, users that you have created to log in and operate the computer (as opposed to users created for an application or service)), in the example below the variable user will receive the result of that

```
user=(`eval getent passwd {$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)..$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)} | cut -d: -f1`)
```

This will loop through the array of users you got from the line above

```
for i in "${!user[@]}"; 
do
```

Here you can run any script you want. For this specific example it will copy the file test.txt from the tmp folder to the Desktop of every user.

```
    cp /tmp/test.txt /home/"${user[i]}"/Desktop; 

done
```

Don't know if there is a simpler answer to this but that's the one I used for my purpose.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.